# How to change UITableViewCell size depending on content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I work with multi platform app, and i want to change cell size depends of contents. Now i have something like this:

[image]

[image]

As you can see cell size are not change, if i will put constrains i will not save proportions images.

How i can fix this?

Comment: Please show  what you've already tried, what didn't work, code samples etc. Please read [ask] and [mcve] and then [edit] your question showing the _minimum_ code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use Auto Layout when creating your table view cells.
Set the table view rowHeight to UITableViewAutomaticDimension.
Set the estimatedRowHeight or implement the height estimation delegate method.

> When you set the rowHeight as UITableViewAutomaticDimension, the table
>   view is told to use the Auto Layout constraints and the contents of
>   its cells to determine each cell’s height.

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140
```

> In order for the table view to do this, you must also provide an
>   estimatedRowHeight. In this case, 140 is just an arbitrary value that
>   works well in this particular instance. For your own projects, you
>   should pick a value that better conforms to the type of data that
>   you’ll be displaying

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to set auto layout right way to use UITableViewAutomaticDimension because your cell sizes are same height.Please control constraints also your problem could be related tableview's height not cell size, in my opinion you should also check tableview constraints in storyboard.